# Fast hiding of Excel shapes without looping (in one sweep)

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

Do any of you know a method to avoid looping through a Worksheet's Shapes inventory -OR- looping through a Range that contains the names of the Shapes? I am trying to avoid loops overall and was thinking if maybe there's some way to mass-gather all of them and do a *Bulk.Visible = False*.

Thanks for taking an interest in this subject!

I've already tried using Arrays of Shape definitions or Joins/Unions to try and get an aggregate of them so the .Visible setting is set in one sweep.

Comment: `activesheet.drawingobjects.visible=false` ?

Comment: What's wrong with looping?

Comment: In my current set-up I have a sheet with 40 Listboxes. These listboxes would be hidden in a loop every time a Worksheet_SelectionChange event occurs. They are hidden and shown for a certain range of Cells(row, column). Furthermore, when clicking on a certain column and depending on the value in the respective cell on that column, a specific Listbox will be shown and not a default one (there can be up to 10 different Listboxes shown depedning on the pre-defined value from that cell, which is also selected from a Listbox). Every time selection changes, all need to be hidden away.

Comment: "ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects.Visible=False" - neat solution, as a starting point. I would have to add that my sheet has: images, textboxes, listboxes. So I want to hide just the listboxes. So I will take a look at @FaneDuru's suggestions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way of doing it is the one suggested by @Tim Williams in the first comment, so the credit should go to him:

```
   Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = ActiveSheet

   sh.DrawingObjects.Visible = msoFalse
   sh.DrawingObjects.Visible = msoTrue
```

But this way uses a property not well documented, even `IntelliSense` does not show it.

That's why the next approach could be considere better, being able to see what else you can do with the object:

```
  Dim shRng As ShapeRange
  Set shRng = sh.DrawingObjects.ShapeRange
  'followed by
  shRng.Visible = msoFalse
  shRng.Visible = msoTrue
```

Another way uses `Range` property of the sheet `Shapes` one:

```
  Dim arrSh()
  arrSh = Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(ROW(1:" & sh.Shapes.count & "))") 'all shapes indexes in an array
  
  sh.Shapes.Range(arrSh).Visible = msoFalse
  sh.Shapes.Range(arrSh).Visible = msoTrue

  sh.Shapes.Range(Array(1,3)).Visible = msoTrue 'makes visible the first and the third shape
```

You may use such a filtered array (obtained by iteration, or directly from the sheet) and then use it as the `Range` array:

```
  Dim arrN(),i As Long, k as Long
  arrN = Application.Transpose(sh.Range("A2:A10").Value2). Supposing that the shapes name to be hiden - unhidden are in "A2:A10" range

  'or obtain it by iteration according to shapes type:
  ReDim arrN(1 To sh.Shapes.count)
  k = 1
  For i = 1 To sh.Shapes.count
    Select Case sh.Shapes(i).Type
        Case msoFormControl, msoOLEControlObject
            'do nothing in case of Form or ActiveX controls
        Case Else
            arrN(k) = sh.Shapes(i).name 'colect control names in the array to be handled
            k = k + 1
    End Select
  Next i
  ReDim Preserve arrN(k - 1) 'remove array empty elements
  
  sh.Shapes.Range(arrN).Visible = msoFalse
  sh.Shapes.Range(arrN).Visible = msoTrue
```

You can also save the shapes indexes in a sheet to not determine it each time and extract it from the range as shown above.

If something not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

**Edited**:

The next part show how to create an array of only List boxes. Not knowing if the involved list boxes are of Form or ActiveX type, the next solution is able to deal with both. Of course, you will keep only what is suitable:

1. Declare the array on top of the (standard) module (in the declarations area), to be used by any other procedure:

```
  Public arrN()
```

2. Use the next `Sub` which does the selection job:

```
Sub extractListBoxes(sh As Worksheet, listBType As MsoControlType)
  Dim i As Long, k As Long
  
  ReDim arrN(sh.Shapes.count) 'redim the necessary array at a maximum possible
  For i = 1 To sh.Shapes.count
    Select Case sh.Shapes(i).Type
        Case listBType
           If listBType = msoOLEControlObject Then
                If TypeOf sh.Shapes(i).OLEFormat.Object.Object Is msforms.listbox Then 'if it is a List Box
                     arrN(k) = sh.Shapes(i).name 'colect ActiveX list box names in the array
                     k = k + 1
                 End If
           ElseIf listBType = msoFormControl Then
                If TypeOf sh.Shapes(i).OLEFormat.Object Is listbox Then 'if it is a List Box
                    arrN(k) = sh.Shapes(i).name 'colect Form list box names in the array
                    k = k + 1
                End If
           End If
    End Select
  Next i
  ReDim Preserve arrN(k - 1)     'remove empty array elements
  Debug.Print Join(arrN, vbCrLf) 'just to visually see the array content in Imediate Window
End Sub
```

3. You can test it using something like:

```
Sub testExtractListBoxes()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   
   Set ws = ActiveSheet 'set here the necessary sheet
   
   If Not Not arrN Then Exit Sub 'this part checks if the array is already loaded and
                                 'in such a case it does  not call the loading Sub, anymore...
   
   extractListBoxes ws, msoOLEControlObject 'if your list boxes are of ActiveX type
   extractListBoxes ws, msoFormControl      'if your list boxes are of Form type
End Sub
```

Since, the array variable is volatile (in case of an error followed by stopping the code in any procedure, it looses its content), you can save its content in a hidden sheet (drop its content in a range), as a last code line in the above `Sub`.

You can load it from there, too. If the array/range need to be modified, adding or removing list boxes you can use `Erase arrN` before the array checking/loading (like an optional parameter of the called `Sub`, to be used only when you need)...

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation. I will do a combination of Type and Name, because all of my Listboxes start with "lbx" and I want to hide only Listboxes (I also have images and textboxes in the sheet). Will return with feedback and a mock-up once I've managed to get it to a final form.

Comment: @SunBeam I only tried answering your question as it has been formulated... Should I understand that my above suggestions did not answer your question? If I missed anything, please do not hesitate to specify what is it about...

Comment: Your suggestions above did answer my questions. I was explaining a bit further what I was facing with here, not asking for more adjustments from your end :) Just went a bit offline to put them to practice and return with feedback. I've marked your solution as the answer to my question. Thanks once more!

Comment: @SunBeam OK, but this was not my concern... I wanted to know what else you (really) need.  I will adapt the answer to contain a code sequence able to place in array only list boxes. It was better to specify **what kind of list boxes** do you use... I will design something allowing to select the respective type.